# I want to pass the data from one VC to another VC

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass the data from one VC to another VC Here is my code.

I am getting errors while running the program. Could you please let me know where am I doing wrong.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ContactPro
//
//  Created by raj on 30/09/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

// Array declaration.
var contactsArray = [Contact]()

// CollectionView Protocols
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    // IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactImgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Getting the data back from the UserDefaults.
        let unarchivedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "contacts") as? Data

        if let unarchivedData = unarchivedData
        {
            contactsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedData) as! [Contact]

            // Unarchiving the data and passing it to the appropriate textFields.
            if contactsArray.count > 0
            {
                let singleContact = contactsArray[0]
                nameLabel.text = singleContact.name
                phoneLabel.text = singleContact.phone

                let imagepath = imagePath(imageName: singleContact.imageName)
                let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagepath.path)

                contactImgView.image = image
            }

            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        rounded(view: contactImgView, radius: 110)
        rounded(view: button, radius: 110)
    }

    // MARK: - CollectionView Methods.
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contactsArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath)

        let imgView = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIImageView

        let contact = contactsArray[indexPath.row]
        let imageName = contact.imageName

        let imagepath = imagePath(imageName: imageName)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagepath.path)
        imgView.image = image

        rounded(view: imgView, radius: 50)
        imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let contact = contactsArray[indexPath.row]
        let imageName = contact.imageName
        let phone = contact.phone
        let name = contact.name

        let imagepath = imagePath(imageName: imageName)
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagepath.path)

        nameLabel.text = name.uppercased()
        phoneLabel.text = phone
        contactImgView.image = image

        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    // Appending image to the Document Path.
    func imagePath(imageName: String) -> URL
    {
        let urlPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let directory = urlPath[0]
        let imagePath = directory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)

        return imagePath
    }

    // Making the view rounded.
    func rounded(view: UIView, radius: CGFloat)
    {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.27, green:0.69, blue:0.60, alpha:1.00).cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 3
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func deleteAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ALERT!",
                                      message: "Image Will get deleted.",
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let Action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) { (action) in
            if let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath{
                contactsArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
                self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
                self.nameLabel.text = ""
                self.phoneLabel.text = ""
                self.contactImgView.image = nil
            }
        }

        let Action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
        }

        alert.addAction(Action1)
        alert.addAction(Action2)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonCliicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editSegue"{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditVC {
                destinationVC.selectedContactIndex = IndexPath.row
            }
        }
    }
}

//
//  EditVC.swift
//  ContactPro
//
//  Created by raj on 7/30/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 . All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class EditVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!

    var selectedContactIndex : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Edit data"

        let imageView = view.viewWithTag(8) as! UIImageView
        let image =  contactsArray [selectedContactIndex]

        let name = view.viewWithTag(9) as! UITextView
        name.text = contactsArray  [selectedContactIndex]

        let phoneNumber = view.viewWithTag(10) as! UITextView
        phoneNumber.text = contactsArray  [selectedContactIndex]
    }

    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: show your errors...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: DO NOT post almost 200 lines of code and just say "I am getting errors." Tell us which line(s) and which error(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it fixes the problem. "selectedContactIndex" must be a var in the destination controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editSegue" {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? EditVC {
                destinationVC.selectedContactIndex = IndexPath.row
    }
  }
}
```